# List the contents of a tar file using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a jsp file in which i am writing a function in javascript that takes as argument, a tar file name and returns a list of the file names of the files that the tar file contains.. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [UnTar.js](https://code.google.com/p/bitjs/source/browse/untar.js?r=0eca1f06d91e1477e3708531939c8071fc877855) ? Its open source js library for that

edit :
providing usage example for clarity

```
function updateProgressBar(e) { ... update UI element ... }
function displayZipContents(e) { ... display contents of the file ... }

var unzipper = new bitjs.archive.Unzipper(zipFileArrayBuffer);
unzipper.addEventListener("progress", updateProgressBar);
unzipper.addEventListener("finish", displayZipContents);
unzipper.start();
```

some more info [here](http://hackersome.com/p/pingjiang/bitjs)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: added usage example and additional source of information as per @JqueryKing suggestion.